# I want to click a parent component to render a child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to click on an option in the menu. This options should then display all the items associated with that option in the child component.  I know I am going wrong in two places. Firstly, I am going wrong in the onClick function. Secondly, I am not sure how to display all the items of ONLY the option (Eg.Brand, Holiday destination, Film)  that is clicked in the child component. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

horizantalscroll.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollMenu from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import './hrizontalscroll.css';
import Items from './items';

// list of items




// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="menu-item"
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};



onclick(){
  this.onClick(name)}

}
// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = (list) => list.map(el => {
  const { name } = el;

  return (
    <MenuItem
      text={name}
      key={name}
      onclick={this.onclick.name}

    />
  );
});


const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
    >{text}</div>
  );
};


const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: '<', className: 'arrow-prev' });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: '>', className: 'arrow-next' });

class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {

  state = {
    selected: 0,
    statelist: [
  {name: "Brands",
    items: ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
  {name: "Films",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  },
  {name: "Holiday Destination",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  }
]

  };




  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });
  }


  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(this.state.statelist, selected);
    const {statelist} = this.state;


    return (
      <div className="HorizantScroller">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />

      <items items={items}/>


      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;
```

items.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HorizontalScroller from "horizontalscroll.js";


class Items extends React.Component{
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.statelist.items.map({items, name}) =>
        name === this.statelist.name && <div>{items}</div>
        }
    </div>
  );
}
}



export default Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in passing to your Items component the correct array it needs to show. You are already creating a state variable for what's selected. So it would be along the lines of:

```
<Items items={items[selected]}/>
```

Comment: So would that line that you have written go into the parent component file?

Comment: It's not a copy paste answer, but you would need to think of  the answer a little bit in detail. It's just a hint that you should select the element when passing it down. Also, the onSelect is saving what is being selected. So your Items component should just receive what it needs to show.